# Git Credential Management - allow to change passwords (Windows, TortoiseGit)

Tags: git, authentication, version-control, credentials, tortoisegit

We want to introduce Git to our company and decided to use TortoiseGit (as TortoiseSVN is already in use).

We already noticed there are huge differences between TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit in saving credentials. In short: To save credentials TortoiseGit uses Git for Windows and Git for Windows uses the chosen credential helper (eg. wincred).

The credential helper saves the credentials in the credential manager of the windows control panel once and for all so you never have to enter your password again.

Sounds great and ready to roll-out but there is a case that causes trouble: What if there are wrong credentials in the credential manager? This could be caused by a mistyped password or even a changed password. 
Our tests have shown that if there are already wrong credentials in the manager, TortoiseGit (indeed Git for Windows) will just use these and fail.

In our opinion the program should ask for the correct (or new) password, if there is a wrong one in the credential store and replace it.

As far as I see we have now two possibilities:

1. We provide the users a manual, how to delete the credentials using the windows credential manager (which IS a solution but the preferred)
2. I ask you if you know **another credential helper, that lets the user *easily change their passwords***

I chose the second one so please help me with your genius!

Thank You & Best Regards
Lukas

Comment: Maybe using https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows is preferable: it has deletion capabilities (https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/search?q=delete&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: But how do you use the delete command with the GUI (TortoiseSVN)?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/39016768/3906760