# Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows also saves invalid credentials

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit, credential-manager

I am using the Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows version 1.6.0 (also tried 1.5.0) from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases

The Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows is included Git for Windows I am using (tried 2.9.3 and 2.9.2) https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

I have the following problem:

If you activate the credential manager and e.g. pull a repository, you get asked for your login-credentials. The credentials get saved in the windows credential manager (of the control panel) and the user won't ever have to retype his credentials.

But if the user mistyped his credentials, or changes his password, the credential manager saves wrong credentials.

I have found the following at the help page of the git-credential-manager-for windows command:

```
    Git Configuration Options:

(...)

  validate     Causes validation of credentials before supplying them
               to Git. Invalid credentials get a refresh attempt
               before failing. Incurs some minor overhead.
               Defaults to TRUE. Ignored by Basic authority.

(...)

  preserve     Prevents the deletion of credentials even when they are
               reported as invalid by Git. Can lead to lockout situations once credentials
               expire and until those credentials are manually removed.
               Defaults to FALSE.
```

I understand this as follows:

The credential-manager **should** validate the credentials (as this is true as default) and **should not** prevent the deletion if they are wrong (as this is false as default)

But the credentials do not get deleted, even if they are wrong!

I have already tried to set "validate" and "preserve" manually in th config file, without success...

I know I could always delete the credentials manually from the control panel, but this is not the solution my company prefers.

Best regards

Lukas

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/31782090/3906760, http://stackoverflow.com/q/38894739/3906760 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/35645177/3906760

Comment: Reported upstream: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/277

Comment: thank you!

did you notice, two of the questions are by me? xD